# XOR string in PHP with key

Tags: php

I need to XOR a string/text in PHP the base64 encode it, but something goes wrong:

```
<?php

$mustget = 'Kw4SCQ==';
$string = 'Josh';

echo("Must get: " . $mustget . "\n");
echo("We got: " . base64_encode(xor_this($string)) . "\n");

function xor_this($text) {
    $key = 'frtkj';
    $i = 0;
    $encrypted = '';
    foreach (str_split($text) as $char) {
        $encrypted .= chr(ord($char) ^ ord($key{$i++ % strlen($key)}));
    }
    return $encrypted;
}

?>
```

I get the following result, but I need to get the "$mustget" one:

```
Must get: Kw4SCQ==
We got: LB0HAw==
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: I'm working on decrypting a malware in the wild that uses that "encryption" to communicate with its PHP admin panel: http://blog.spiderlabs.com/2012/12/the-dexter-malware-getting-your-hands-dirty.html

Comment: Question is, how did you get that result `$mustget = 'Kw4SCQ=='` ?

Comment: @xtmtrx: "Each character in the decoded string is xored sequentially against each character of the key we previously identified". So you should `xor` each data character with each key character

Comment: 1.The data is Base64 decoded
2.Each character in the decoded string is xored sequentially against each character of the key we previously identified. In Ruby, it looks something like this:
 
                "A".xor("f").xor("r").xor("t").xor("k").xor("j")

Comment: @xtmtrx: right `"A".xor("f").xor("r").xor("t").xor("k").xor("j")` --- you `xor` data character with **every** key character, not with one

Comment: You say I have to XOR it 5 times???

Comment: @xtmtrx: Not me, but the article does that --- `"A".xor("f").xor("r").xor("t").xor("k").xor("j")`

Comment: Is there a simple way in PHP to do that? Seems what I tried to do above is completely wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$mustget = 'Kw4SCQ==';

$key = 'frtkj';
$key_length = strlen($key);

$encoded_data = base64_decode($mustget);

$result = '';

$length = strlen($encoded_data);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $tmp = $encoded_data[$i];

    for ($j = 0; $j < $key_length; $j++) {
        $tmp = chr(ord($tmp) ^ ord($key[$j]));
    }

    $result .= $tmp;
}

echo $result; // Josh
```

http://ideone.com/NSIe7K

I'm sure you can reverse it and create a function, that "crypts" the data ;-)

Comment: Modulo is your friend !