# The php bitwise XOR operator ^ (caret) with integers

Tags: php

Hi i was just wondering if someone can explain to me how the following php code evaluates to 5

```
 <?php
      $a = 12 ^ 9;
      echo $a;
 ?>
```

so I know the output will be 5, but can someone explain to me how this works?

Comment: meh.... homework detected!

Comment: nope. Trying to learn things. But good try snarky ZF007

Comment: ... why its homework/duplicate... check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2674920/8928024) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/249423/8928024) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13875762/8928024).

Comment: lol its still not homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand the process, php converts the numbers into binary and performs an XOR operation on them.

```
12 -> 1100
9  -> 1001
1100 XOR 1001 = 0101 = 5.
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me visualize the answer

Answer (score 3):

The `^` operator as you say is bitwise, so it converts the integer to a binary value.

`12` is `00001100` in binary.

`9`  is `00001001` in binary.

```
A:       00001100  12
          XOR(^)
B:       00001001   9
         ---------
Output:  00000101   5
```

It is simply `1` if **only** one of the inputs is `1`, here is the truth table for XOR:

```
+---+---+--------+
| A | B | Output |
+---+---+--------+
| 0 | 0 | 0      |
+---+---+--------+
| 0 | 1 | 1      |
+---+---+--------+
| 1 | 0 | 1      |
+---+---+--------+
| 1 | 1 | 0      |
+---+---+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
12  = 1100
09  = 1001
Xor = 0101 = 5
```

Exclusive or means only 1 bit at the same position to be high.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me visualize the answer